# Oracle: concatenate with NULL

Tags: oracle, null, concatenation, coalesce

It appears that in Oracle, `'a'||NULL` give you `a`, which is not my experience in other DBMSs.

This means that an expression like `coalesce('id: '||id,'missing')` won’t work, since the first expression is never `NULL`.

I suppose I can use a `CASE … END` expression to get the job done, but that’s starting to go over the top.

How can I get the concatenation to return `NULL`, or is there some other simple trick I should be using?

Comment: What about `'id: '|| nvl(id,'missing')` seems more consistent for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle exhibits mixed behavior with NULLs. On the one hand, there are several functions like `GREATEST`, `LEAST`, etc.. that will return `NULL` if a single operand is `NULL`. On the other hand, aggregations like `MAX`, `MIN`, `SUM`, `AVG` will conveniently ignore NULLs during aggregation. Similarly, string operators treat `NULL` as an empty string. In fact, `''` is equivalent to `NULL` for a string datatype. We regularly rely on this to assemble concatenated strings with optional/conditional, dynamically generated additions. You wouldn't want an email body to be blank because some piece of your message body that you spliced in happened to be NULL.

In terms of `coalesce('id: '||id,'missing')`, here are some options:

```
DECODE(id,NULL,'missing','id: '||id) -- works in SQL only, not in PL/SQL

CASE WHEN (id IS NULL) THEN 'missing' ELSE 'id: '||id END

NVL(NULLIF('id: '||id,'id: '),'missing')
```

Comment: Ah, that’s it. `''` is equivalent to `NULL` for strings. I know it makes some operations easier, but I really think that `NULL` should be allowed to be `NULL`. Thanks.

Comment: Or use `NVL2(id, 'id: '||id, 'missing')` (or the other way around, I am always mistaken it).

Comment: @Wernfried, that's even better.. one less argument than DECODE